# Intellisense terminal on vscode

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal, intellisense

How can I enable intellisense in the terminal in vscode?
When I start typing, automatically hints come out on the side.
I post an image as an example(In this image, I type with and alongside in light gray I get the suggestions). Thanks.

[image: EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VS Code does **not** support IntelliSense inside the integrated Terminal window.

The auto-suggestion feature in your screenshot comes from a Z shell plug-in called ["zsh-autosuggestions"](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions). You may check out that repository's [INSTALL.md readme page](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/blob/master/INSTALL.md) to learn how to install the plug-in in your Z-shell.

Note: Z shell ("zsh" in short) is a Unix shell that can be run in Linux or MacOS. If you are a Windows user, [check out this guide](https://dev.to/zinox9/installing-zsh-on-windows-37em) on how to install Z shell using Windows Subsystem Linux.

Answer (score 4):

you've probably already figured it out, but for the next person switching to VS Code: right arrow key